# Collapse rows into buckets in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dataset in PostgreSQL:

```
row_id, wind_speed_category, timestamp
1, 3, 2021-01-20 10:00:01
2, 3, 2021-01-21 11:00:01
3, 3, 2021-01-21 12:00:01
4, 4, 2021-01-21 14:00:01
5, 4, 2021-01-23 10:00:01
6, 3, 2021-02-22 10:00:01
```

I would like to collapse the rows into "running" buckets, so getting a result somewhat like:

```
wind_speed_category, interval_seconds
3, 86400
4, 2764800
3, 0
```

The `interval_seconds` is based upon the interval of timestamp in first row in the `bucket` and `last row + 1` in bucket.

I've managed to get this far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3c55e/1
But don't know how to collapse into buckets/partitions/windows.

Comment: You'll want to use windowing-functions. They're called "partitions", not "buckets" though (btw, windowing-function partitions are a distinct concept to table-partitions btw)

Comment: Your result is wrong. Line 4 comes before line 2. There are 5 buckets, not three.

Comment: you are correct, I've updated the data input. Sorry.

Comment: Still wrong. Line 6 comes before line 5. There are four buckets now.

Comment: I've tried to create this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3c55e/1

Comment: @AlfredBalle This is a classic gaps and islands problem.  The source of confusion and comments is that your records weren't ordered ascending (or descending), they were in no real order.  This makes it hard to see the gaps and islands, hence your expected output was also off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and the first thing needed to solve it is to order all records ascending or descending by timestamp, across the entire table.  Once this is done, we can try the following:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wind_speed_category
                                 ORDER BY timestamp) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT wind_speed_category,
       EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (MAX(timestamp) - MIN(timestamp))) AS interval_seconds
FROM cte
GROUP BY wind_speed_category, rn1-rn2;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo